# Using GZipStream for Client/Server Async Communication

Tags: c#, client, client-server

I have Client/Server System (using Socket) with multiple clients and single server, which is sending xml datas every seconds on all clients.

The XML datas are always in different size between 1 - 18000 characters and server needs to send these XML-Datas to all clients at the same time.

Now I want to know, how to make the communication between the server and clients faster.

Maybe I will ask more then one Question, but I am really stucked at this point and I can't continue anymore.

- Should I **compress** every XML-Data before sending?
- Should I **serialize** the XML-Datas? (maybe the xml data size will be decreased)
- Do I need to convert every XML-Datas into byte[] array(for buffer), 
  because the communication must be done at the sametime for all clients.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a middle layer with built in pub-sub topology if you are currently iterating through your connected clients.  [0MQ](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3aclr) has the ability for a single publisher to send to n subscribers very efficiently and has a C# binding.  You could also compress the messages before being sent as you suggested.

Comment: Is there any 0MQ compress benchmark list? I am very strange to 0QM. Can I use it for my system?

Comment: From the docs:  "It's sockets on steroids".  It's a middle-ware that is capable of taking a lot of the difficulty out of network communication.  "ØMQ (ZeroMQ, 0MQ, zmq) looks like an embeddable networking library but acts like a concurrency framework. It gives you sockets that carry whole messages across various transports like in-process, inter-process, TCP, and multicast. You can connect sockets N-to-N with patterns like fanout, pub-sub, task distribution, and request-reply. It's fast enough to be the fabric for clustered products."  It can do a lot for you and make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you work on an intranet, I would recommend to [multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast) your xml data. That way, your server would send a single copy of xml data every second (instead of sending N copies of data for N client)

Comment: What if I dont work on intranet? Is there another way to multicast the xml data?

Comment: It depends on your ISP, most probably no.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `WCF` you can easily integrate GZip compression.

check here: [WCF Compression over HTTP sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WCF-Compression-Example-9ffab49c)

Comment: Sorry forgot to say, this is an application using socket (tcp)